# Unable to delete new line if it is last character in text area flex as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[               
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var str:String = textId.text;
            }               
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>               
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:TextArea id="textId" restrict="^\r"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Button label="Click Here" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
    </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

first enter text as: "hi`\n`" in text area, see the text in textId.text by clicking button. Now delete the last character so text is "hi". but in textId.text still result showing as "hi`\n`". The new line at the end is not deleted.

Comment: I tested you code and it's working fine. You can alert the str value and check it. May be some other thing will effect it. Can you please post other code which is used.

Comment: hi ketan,
dont see the text in alert, see it in debugging mode  "textId.text".
Its displaying correctly but the "textId.text" will save in server and it will be displayed later. "textId.text" is still holding the newline character even we delete it.

Comment: What code you have written to save in server side?

Comment: Ketan, before it going to save in server side, i have checked it and it is displaying that new line char in debugging mode ("textId.text) Inspect this variable there

Comment: @ketan 
waiting for your reply mr.ketan
I think this is sdk issue,can you please look into this?

Comment: I have check your code here in my side. And it's working fine. Don't now why there not working

Comment: When im tring to delete new line character, changeHandler() also not calling and it is fired if i delete any other character.
There is a problem with new line character.

Comment: Which SDK you are using?

Comment: Ohh too old. I think you should any new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save whitespace characters from the beginning and end of the entered text in the **TextArea** you can use **trim** *function* as below:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    import mx.utils.StringUtil;
    protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var str:String = StringUtil.trim(textId.text);
        textId.text = str;
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

**trim** function converts " hi`\n\n`" to "hi".

Comment: I dont want to skip white spaces. I am trying to delete new line special character in text area, but it doesn't delete from text area. But displaying correctly, in debugging mode only we can see this.
And imp point here is i have added changeHandler() for textArea , when i delete any character it's fired but when i delete new line character it doesn't fired.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a bug in flash...

The `TextArea` control internally has a `flash.text.TextField` control which, under certain conditions, fails to properly emit an `Event( Event.CHANGE )`.  The `TextArea` control uses this change event to update its internal properties (which includes its own `.text` property).  here are two such situations where this bug seems to occur:

- When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the cursor at the end of the text input where that text input previously ended in non-whitespace.
- When you press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove the newline at the end of the text input and the text prior to that newline is non-whitespace.

The latter situation is the one to which you are referring.  The newline at the end of the internal `flash.text.TextField` control *is removed*, but the `TextArea`'s `.text` property is not correctly updated to reflect the change.

Here is a very ugly workaround:

```actionscript-3
private function onTextAreaKeyUp( event : KeyboardEvent ) : void
{
    // manually dispatch change event, causing TextArea's properties to
    // be updated in certain situations where flash's TextField control
    // fails to emit one automatically
    switch( event.keyCode ) {
    case 46: // delete
    case 13: // backspace
    case 8:  // return
        var target : UITextField = event.target as UITextField;
        target.dispatchEvent( new Event( Event.CHANGE ) );
    }
}

<mx:TextArea keyUp="onTextAreaKeyUp( event );" />
```

If you find a better workaround, I'd love to know!